# Trigger event while typing in a JTextComponent java

Tags: java, swing, events, jtextfield, jtextcomponent

I have a `Settings` class that should provide interface for retrieving settings and saving them to a file. My settings are supposed to update whenever I change input values (rather than after clicking Save button). This is why I added this method to `Settings` class:

```
  /** Automatically update setting value as user types.
   * @param setting_name What is the name of associated setting?
   * @param input JTextComponent (like JTextField) to listen on for events
   */
  public void listenOnInput(final String setting_name, final JTextComponent input) {
    //Debug output
    System.out.println("Settings[\""+setting_name+"\"] automatically updates on input change.");
    input.addInputMethodListener(new InputMethodListener() {
      @Override
      public void inputMethodTextChanged(InputMethodEvent event) {
        //Set setting to current value
        setSetting(setting_name, input.getText());
      }
      //This method is dummy, I see no use for it
      @Override
      public void caretPositionChanged(InputMethodEvent event) {}
    });
  }
```

It's probably not perfect design, but my application will never have complex settings therefore I don't put so much effort in this task. I use it like this:

```
    JTextField name = new JTextField();
    Settings settings = new Settings();
    name.setToolTipText("Enter your name");
    contentPane.add(name);
    settings.listenOnInput("user_name", name);
```

My problem is that the code above doesn't work - I can type or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> but the `inputMethodTextChanged` is never called.

So what's proper method of obtaining the value on update?

Comment: I don't believe `JTextField` supports `InputMethodListener`, you should consider using a `DocumentListener` or a `InputVerifer` or a `FocusListener`

Comment: But none of the methods in `JTextField` or `JTextComponent` supports this listener.

Comment: `JTextField#getDocument`, see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Comment: What [IME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method) are you using? `InputMethodListener` works fine for me when inputting Japanese characters.

Comment: @aterai I just type - and I expected this should trigger that event which doesn't seem to be true.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `DocumentListener` on the `JTextField`'s document:

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(...);
```

You can then use it to detect any change in the text.